# Pass Handlebars variable to JSP tag

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, handlebars.js, jstl

I have a use case in which I would need to pass the value rendered on Handlebars template to a JSP tag, as a variable.

To start with, I define a Map<> in my controller, and pass that Map<> to a JSP view, as follows:

**MyController.java**

```
public ModelAndView personView(HttpServletRequest req) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/personView.jsp");

    Map<Long, String> personMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put(1L, "Bob");
    myMap.put(2L, "Brad");
    myMap.put(3L, "Carol");
    myMap.put(4L, "Kevin");
    myMap.put(5L, "Ned");

    mav.addObject("PersonMap", personMap);
    return mav;
}
```

Then from a **JSP**, I would normally access the personID, like this:

```
<div> Person: ${PersonMap[1]}</div> // renders as "Bob"
```

My **Handlebars** template normally work like this:

```
{{personId}} // renders a number, ie 1
```

Now I would need to combine those two, and do a map lookup based on the Handlebars value that is rendered, and pass that value (the ID) as a key to a map in JSP, something like follows would be ideal:

```
<div> Person: ${PersonMap[{{personId}}]}</div>
```

where the `{{personId}}` replaces the hardcoded "1". But this syntax doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve such thing?

Comment: Handlebars templates are processed by the browser, JSPs are processed on the server before the response is sent to the browser. So, don't think you can use handlebars for this case.

Comment: @DarrenParker Oh... Any other idea how to achieve what I want? Which basically is have the mappings on the server side, and get keys on the client side (AJAX response). Now I need to display the corresponding mappings. For example if AJAX gets me "1", I need to do a lookup for that "1" in a map that is on the server side.